# Does anyone knows a basic javascript calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar

of course I already googled it but...

...there are plenty :(

What I'm searching for is a simple calendar to select a date.
(and have that date readable in a variable)
(period).

There are plenty

1. you need to pay for
2. with (unneeded) whistles and bells
3. that make things overly complicated :(

If you can give me pointers on how to google something like this,
it would already be a help...
(I'm not really apt in searching for frameworks/plug-ins)...

Thanks!!!

S.

Comment: something like this? https://github.com/year-calendar/js-year-calendar , https://github.com/jackducasse/caleandar

Comment: Something like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: @CharlesBamford: indeed, thank you!!! (if you put it in an answer I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html 5 includes a lot of widgets that had to be constructed in previous web standards, including a calendar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

To each his own and the following advice may look overly complicated but it meets at least 2 out of 3 of your asks in *my* opinion.

1. No extra whistles and bells
2. you don't nee to pay for

https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/

## Why?

- Accessible
- Choose your flavor, JS, React, Angular etc.
- Styling, community support
- Enhances for things users may need - keyboard controls.